# I need to set value in dropdown using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to set value "DO RESEARCH ON"

Code is like this :

```
<div class="btn-group select bb-search-action-dropdown actionItem screen-block-z-index open">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Do research on</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
    </button><span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu custom-icn custom-icn-anim" role="menu" style="max-height: 118px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 96px;">
        <li rel="0" class=""><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">I would like to</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Do research on</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="2"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left"> Get a quote for</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="3"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Check my eligibility for</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="4"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Create an application</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="5"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Talk to our help team</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="btn-group select bb-search-action-dropdown actionItem screen-block-z-index open"><button class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Do research on</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button><span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>

Comment: please don't put blobs of code in comments ... edit the question itself to add them. Also need a far better description of your problem and show what you have tried to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group select bb-search-action-dropdown actionItem screen-block-z-index open">
    <button id="drop" class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Do research on</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
    </button><span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu custom-icn custom-icn-anim" role="menu" style="max-height: 118px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 96px;">
        <li rel="0" class=""><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">I would like to</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Do research on</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="2"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left"> Get a quote for</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="3"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Check my eligibility for</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="4"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Create an application</span></a>
        </li>
        <li rel="5"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Talk to our help team</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$("#drop").val("Do Research On");
```

Comment: `#drop` is a `<ul>` ... no `value` on that tag